# Python - Implementing Functions

Tags: python

I am creating a function to check x is greater than y, and if not it switches the two values and returns them.

```
def xGreater(x, y):
    if(y > x):
        x, y = y, x
    return x, y
```

My query is what is the best way to go about using this function within another function, my current code is the following:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    x , y = xGreater(x, y)
    r = x % y
    while(r != 0):
        x, y = y, r
        r = x % y
    return y
```

Can I not simply call xGreater(x, y) to alter the values of x and y, without the x, y = in front? Or does this only work when there is a single variable being returned. Thanks!

Comment: you can't because integers are immutables in python

Comment: By the way, there's no need for parentheses around expressions (in your `if` and `while` statements).

Comment: @thkang Integers being immutable has nothing to do with it. `func(a)` can never change what the local name `a` refers to in the calling scope, regardless of what kind of value that name refers to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I not simply call xGreater(x, y) to alter the values of x and y, without the x, y = in front?

I am afraid you can't, since `x` and `y` are immutable and are passed into `xGreater()` by value.

It can be done in some special cases (for example, if `x` and `y` were two lists), but not generally.

To be totally honest, I'd get rid of `xGreater()` and just do the swap in `gcd()`:

```
def gcd(x, y):
    if y > x:
        x, y = y, x
    r = x % y
    ...
```

I personally find the code more readable this way.

Comment: thanks, this is how I originally had it, but my teacher is always saying we should try to split out our functions more.

Comment: @h1h1: What your teacher is saying is a good general guideline. It's just knowing when to stop that can be a little tricky at times, but that comes with experience.

Answer (score 2):

No, integers are immutable. But hey, you can cut down on one instance of tuple packing/unpacking:

```
def xGreater(x, y):
    return (y, x) if y > x else (x, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

NPE has a better solution but I'm bored and wanted to write some bit hacks

```
def gcd(x,y):
    minVal = y ^((x ^ y) & -(x < y))

    if ( minVal == y ):
        y = x ^ y  # Swapping values without a intermediate variable
        y = y ^ y  # This is highly inefficient to use.
        x = x ^ y  # But still kinda cool.

   return x % y
```